# Map the value of array of object into object properties

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How do I make array of object value into object property? I want to turn this

```
const array = [
  {
    "age_group": [
      {
        "range": "0-20",
        "total_count": 100
      },
      {
        "range": "21-30",
        "total_count": 200
      },
    ],
    "machine": {
      "name": "SK2DS0011",
    }
  }
]
```

into this

```
[{name: "SK2DS0011", "0-20": 100, "21-30": 200}]
```

I'm stuck at using reduce.

```
temp_arr = ori.reduce((accum, arr, i) => {
  return accum['abc'] = arr.age_data.map(o => ({[o.range]: o.count}))
},{})
```

Maybe I'm using map wrong within my reduce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this solution without using `reduce`. Instead use `map` to construct the new array:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    "age_group": [
      {
        "range": "0-20",
        "total_count": 100
      },
      {
        "range": "21-30",
        "total_count": 200
      },
    ],
    "machine": {
      "name": "SK2DS0011",
    }
  }
];

// Use map to format the new array with the desired properties
let result = arr.map((x) => {
  // Get the 'name' property
  let obj = {
    name: x.machine.name,    
  };

  // Iterate over the 'age_group' array and add one property for each element
  var thisTotal = 0;
  for (var k in x.age_group) {
    let a = x.age_group[k];
    obj[a.range] = a.total_count;

    // Add this range to total
    thisTotal += a.total_count;
  }

  // Add the 'total' property
  obj.total = thisTotal;

  // Return the final array
  return obj;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: you could explain this a bit more and not just dump code

Comment: possible to use functional technique?

Comment: what if I want to have a property call total and it sum up all the range?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array#map` to generate your array of object. For each `age_group` you can use `array#map`, spread syntax and `Object.assign()`
to create the range and total_count object. You can use `array_reduce` to generate the sum of all ranges.

```js
const array = [{ "age_group": [{ "range": "0-20", "total_count": 100 }, { "range": "21-30", "total_count": 200 }, ], "machine": { "name": "SK2DS0011", } }],
      result = array.map(({age_group, machine}) => {
        const {name} = machine;
        const obj = Object.assign(...age_group.map(({range, total_count}) => ({[range] : total_count})));
        const total = age_group.reduce((s,o) => s + +o.total_count, 0);
        return {name, ...obj, total};
      });
console.log(result);
```

Comment: nice but this too much destructing version make things hard to read.